# Using ArcMap georeferencing in AutoCAD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, georeferencing, proj, autocad

I am working on a project in ArcMap.

I added an auto cad .dwg to my map, and in ArcMap, and I Georeferenced this .dwg file.

So now the DWG drawing is moved to be exactly on my drawing in ArcMap.

I digitized everything in ArcMap and exported this file to AutoCAD. But my drawing exported was so far.

I think because when I georeferenced an AutoCAD file in ArcMap, in AutoCAD(when I open the file)
it will still be in the old location without georeferencing.

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: You can georeference the file into CAD, than open in arcmap.

Comment: export to dwg/dxf and xref in AutoCAD?

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in AutoCAD.
It was successfully done by [**Align**] command.